# std::stoi not throwing std::invalid_argument

Tags: c++

If I am doing something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "123abc";
    auto i = std::stoi(s);
    std::cout << i; // prints 123
}
```

The program is not throwing any exception. What to do in case I want an exception instead of `123` here?

Comment: Supply `pos` and detect that the whole string has not been processed see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `pos` argument of [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), I was able to write the following function, which does the job for me.

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

int stoi_strict(const std::string &str, int base = 10) {
    int res;
    std::size_t pos = 0;
    try {
        res = std::stoi(str, &pos, base);
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument &ia) {
        // will be thrown later but with a diff msg
        // it is added just to maintain consistency
    }
    if (pos != str.size())
        throw std::invalid_argument("stoi_strict: no conversion");
    return res;
}
```

Thanks to [Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten) for pointing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966945/stdstoi-not-throwing-stdinvalid-argument#comment116634077_65966945) out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

> Discards any whitespace characters (as identified by calling
> isspace()) until the first non-whitespace character is found, then
> takes as many characters as possible

If you take a look at the examples, you will notice that `"31337 with words"`is a valid number from std::stoi point of view.

You can check if the string s contains only numbers using this C++11 one-liner:

```
!s.empty() && std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isdigit);
```

Comment: Your code won't handle numbers with sign (`+`/`-` is not a digit). What Richard said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966945/stdstoi-not-throwing-stdinvalid-argument/65967002#comment116634077_65966945) seems a much better solution. One just needs to check `pos != s.size()` before throwing exception in that case.

Comment: Besides, `isdigit` causes UB when you give it chars with values < -1.